# Как правильно подключить D3 js ? Ошибка d3 is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Установил d3js через npm

```
npm install d3
```

добавил в модуль код (код работает на [codepen](https://codepen.io/Divatoz/pen/WNodKXB?editors=0010)). Подключил d3.min.js

```
import 'd3/dist/d3.min.js';

// js код с codepen
```

Диаграмма не отображается и в консоли выдаёт ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было добавить

```
var d3 = require("d3");
```

Comment: хм. тогда почему на codepen работает без этого?

Comment: import работает если script type=module